# How to implement type information for static code analylsis tool for a custom JVM language?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-languages, java-runtime-compiler

I have to implement a static code analysis tool for a custom JVM language and I would like to have most of the methods that are accessible in the Java `Class<?>` class like for example: `getDeclaredMethods(): Method[]`.
I have come up with two approaches:

1) Compile all classes so that I have then .class files on which I can call javap and then results from the javap save to the java source files and use the Java type information.

2) Use antlr4 and create the same class structures as are accesible in Java.
Maybe there is some other approach?

I feel like the option 2 is reinventing the wheel or maybe is it the valid approach?
I think that option number 1 would be better but I am not sure weather this is doable at all... and then it's not really a static code analysis because I need to have all the files of my custom language compiled.

Could you help me please or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: The term “custom JVM language” implies something that runs on the JVM, hence must be represented as classes that can already be accessed and inspected via `java.lang.Class`. It’s not clear what your two alternative detours through several tools, each of them finally ending up at what you already have at the beginning, is supposed to add. You have to explain a lot more about what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Let's say that this language is for example Scala (but it's not it's a different language for which as a result a *.class file for the JVM is produced). The syntax of the language is a bit different than Java. Having not compiled source code file of my custom language I would like to read that file(files) somehow and after that have an API like for Java.Class with the minimum effort. I hope that this is more clear now?

Comment: Not really. What do you mean with “*Having not compiled source code file of my custom language*”? If you don’t have a compiler for your language, you don’t have a “jvm-language”. And the first step of your variant 1) is to *compile* the sources. And then you already have what Reflection is using. What does your idea of subsequently “*call javap and then results from the javap save to the java source files*” give you what the compiled `.class` files don’t already have? Is it the “*and use the Java type information*” that apparently is not the builtin Reflection?

Comment: "Having not compiled source code file of my custom language" - it doesn't mean that I don't have compiler for my langauge it means that I would like to have an information about classes before compilation. I would like to have for each of my classes a static Class instance available like in Java. For example String.class returns Class<String>, correct? Again I hope that now this is more clear...

Comment: But `Java`’s `Class` instance provides reflective information *at runtime* only, based on the parsed `.class` files. You can use class literals in source code, because *the compiler* obviously knows which classes are present when compiling. So for Java, no static code analysis tool other the the actual compiler is involved. All `javac` does for `Foo.class`, is to prove that `Foo` exists and is accessible at compile-time. Then, a symbolic reference to the class, merely consisting of the class’ name is stored in the code. At runtime, the symbolic reference will be converted to a `Class` instance